# Swift: how to store array of custom objects in Core Data?

Tags: class, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject, transformable

Using `Swift` and `Core Data`, I want to store an array of custom `Game` objects in my custom `User` class in the database.

The `GameOwned` variable is a `Transformable`. I want to be able to store `[Game]` inside the database.

How can I go about achieving this? Is there anything special I need to do in order to be able to read it once I pull it from the database other than casting it to `[Game]`?

**User Class**

```
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var gameOwned: AnyObject
}
```

**Game Class**

```
class Game: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var coverPhoto: String
    @NSManaged var genre: String
    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var isActive: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var isOwned: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var platform: String

}
```

Comment: create one-to-many relationship as an option

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov where do I create this relationship? possible in the interface builder?

Comment: @TheNomad Can you please post step by step solution about how you achieved this one. As at my end, I have "Album" and "AlbumImages" two entities. I want to access an array of album images using album entity. Can you please let me know the steps and the things I need to add to the class files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Game` is already a Core Data object. You need to set a relationship between `User` and `Game`. It should be to-many, and you could call it `games`.

Relationships are very basic Core Data concepts. You do this in the Core Data model editor in Xcode. Please read up on this first in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-185436-TPXREF147).

Once you have this setup, you can access the related items very simply.

```
var aGame = user.games.anyObject as? Game
```

The above is optional because there might be no games, etc.